# MQTT connection issue on cygwin environment

Tags: python-2.7

I have installed mqtt python client(PAHO) on cygwin environment. I have mqtt broker running on my board. I am trying to connect to local broker (127.0.0.1) but it is giving me following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
      self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2287, in _thread_main
    self.loop_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1290, in loop_forever
    self.reconnect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 688, in reconnect
    raise ValueError('Invalid host.')
ValueError: Invalid host.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestSuite_Main.py", line 146, in <module>
    STObj.IOhandler()
  File "TestSuite_Main.py", line 47, in IOhandler
```

Note: My same code works on linux fine. Please help on same.